# Unable to rename attribute table columns using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, rename

[image]

I'm using QGIS and trying to remove the "ACS block group" prefix from each field in this attribute table.  When I try to rename my attribute columns it says "Failed to rename field to ...Is this field unique?"

It is a unique field, so what else might be happening?

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the data source? could this maybe be a reserved name? does it work when renaming it to another name? or without capital letters?

Comment: It won't let me change the field to any name; I tried a few.  I think it may have to do with the fact that these field names are the result of a join.  Here is the data I'm using: https://gisdata.mn.gov/dataset/us-mn-state-metc-society-census-acs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to rename a field created by a table join. You can't rename a field there - go to the joins tab an make your changes there (for `Custom field name prefix`, if you have defined any) or in the original tables that you join. Then probably your join has to be created from the scratch, so be careful with renaming. At least the `Target field` and `Join field` will not work  any more if you change them and you have to define them again.

According to your description, I guess the `ACS block group` is the prefix set in the joins tab - so that should be easy to change. But be aware: if you have any "links" to fieldnames in your project (like in virtual fields or virtual layers), they will not work any more if changing field names. So reflect what consequences renaming in your case will result and if renaming pays off.

You could also use field alias. See in the [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?highlight=rename%20fields#fields-properties) for more information. There you also find some information about the fact that depending on datatype, some options are restricted. If using shpefiles, your fieldnames can contain [max. 10 characters](http://switchfromshapefile.org/#10characters).

For regular (not joined) fields remains valid what I stated in my first answer:
The error message means that you already have a field with the same name. So somewhere in your quite long list there already exists a field named `GEOG_UNIT`. If you change the name to a string that does not yet exist as fieldname, it should work.

Fields should have unique names - otherwise you are not able to refer to them.

Be aware that not all kind of layers offer the possibility to rename fields - see thedocumentation linked above for details.

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to edit fields from the joins tab?  I edited my post to include a screenshot of what it looks like, and I don't see any way to edit from there.

Comment: You can only change the prefix in the joins tab: in your screenshot, double click on join layer, in the opening dialog, at the bottom you can define the prefix, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pAeL.png

Comment: Be careful what you change - when you already have "linked" your fields (like virtual fields or virtual layers), they will not work properly any more without setting them manually to the new values

Comment: I'm only renaming the fields because of the issue from the first screenshot that I had when exporting to a new shapefile.  But, you're right, renaming the fields is causing more problems than leaving them.  QGIS keeps crashing now, even after I erased the join and tried it again.  But I don't understand the problem with the first error I got.  If you have a long field value name are you not allowed to create a shapefile from it?

Comment: You can save it as a shapefile, but fieldnames will be cut to the first 10 characters. Try saving as Geopackage, it doesn't have this limitation

Comment: Ah, I see, the error message is because of the fact that several fields get the same name when you cut it to the first 10 characters: all joined fields will have the same name: CensusACSB, that's not possible, every field has to have a unique name. One of the reasons why there are recomandations to switch from Shapefile to Geopackage: http://switchfromshapefile.org

Comment: I was under the impression that you can't directly work with geopackage.  I downloaded it as a geopackage, but when I clicked on and opened it the separate shapefiles were listed below.

Comment: Do you mean ESRI File Geodatabase? If I click the link in your very first comment, I can't find any Geopackage to download. Don't get confused: File Geodatabase is not the same as Geopackage!

Comment: Have a look here for GIS formats: https://gisgeography.com/gis-formats/

Comment: The geopackage I was talking about is from the shapefile I'm joining:https://gisdata.mn.gov/dataset/us-mn-state-metc-society-census2010realign

Comment: OK, I see. The Geopackage is zipped together with metadata - first unzip it, than you can use it with QGIS - drag and drop the .gpkg file to the QGIS window.